# ReactJS and Redux: unable to render user search data to UI

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am unable to render the data to UI that I got from getGitUser function (action.js file). When I debugged  my function `getGitUsers()` (in reducer-user.js) it shows something as

> ***ReferenceError: action is not defined at eval (eval at  (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2113:2)), :1:1) at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2113:2), :8:21) at Object. (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2113:2) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:20:30) at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2125:2), :19:15) at Object. (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2125:2) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:20:30) at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2119:2), :11:17) at Object. (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:2119:2) at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:3000/js/bundle.min.js:20:30)
>   message
>   :
>   "action is not defined"
>   stack
>   :
>   "ReferenceError: action is not def***

Comment: Here is the code:  https://github.com/Zamm9090/assessment

Comment: You probably shouldn't post this code publicly. You have access tokens visible in the code. Someone can take them and make requests against the github API as if it was you. You should hide those into a JS file that is under `.gitignore` so it is not committed to your code

Comment: I don't see how you have that error in the reducer. You have default arguments, so it's not possible that action will ever be undefined (but it could be null). `export function getGitUsers(state = [], action ={}) {` action is always going to be an empty object at least.

Comment: If you could fix the source maps it'd make it a lot easier to figure out what's going on

Comment: I would try to remove the redux-promise and logger middleware to see if one of those is causing an issue. The redux-promise one may be. based on the code you have, you only need redux-thunk enabled for it to work